# How to prove if this is a logical equivalence?

Tags: logic

Here's the question, I'm supposed to determine whether the statement is valid or invalid but first i have to prove it using logical equivalences (like DeMorgan, associativity, etc..). For this one, I have no idea where to start except that i should work on the left side (since the right is pretty simplified). Other than that, no idea since the p and ¬p are confusing me. Thanks for the help.

(c) ((p v q) ∧ (¬p v r)) ≡ (q v r)

Comment: You can use `$$ .. $$` characters to display math text appropriately

Comment: I got  (p(OR)¬p) OR (q(AND)r), then TRUE (OR) (q(AND)r) is TRUE, then TRUE = q v r which is false

Answer (score 1):

See what happens when $p$ is true, and when it's false.

Answer (score 0):

The two are **not** equivalent.

Consider a truth-assignement $v$ such that :

> $v(p)=v(q)=$ **f** and $v(r)=$ **t**.

With it we have $v(q \lor r)=$ **t** and $v(p \lor q)$= **f**; thus : $v((p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r))=$ **f**.

Of course :

> $(p \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor r) \vDash (q \lor r)$

as we can easily see rewriting the LHS as :

> > $(\lnot q \to p) \land (p \to r)$.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you not allowed to use truth tables? Since the statement is false it becomes easy to see using truth table, you'll get a discrepancy when $p$ and $q$ are false while $r$ is true.

If it's an assignment where the requirement is that you don't use a truth table, then you solve that by using a truth table and then note this discrepancy and note's that with these values the RHS does not imply the LHS and use that fact in your solution (then you don't hand in the truth table). Also the truth table show you what your task is - if the truth table is affirmative your task is to prove the statement, otherwise your task is to disprove it (so you don't have to try to disprove a true statement or prove a false statement).

What you should show is fx:

$(\neg p \land \neg q \land r) \rightarrow ((q \lor p) \land \neg((p\lor q)\land(\neg p \lor q)))$